# Universal class for Mac OS and iOS

Tags: swift

I want to create a class for a Mac OS- and a iOS-App. Unfortunately, I can't use NSColor for iOS and no UIColor for Mac OS.

Actually I have the following code:

```
#if os(iOS)
    func myFunc(color: UIColor?) {
        self.myFuncX(color)
    }
#elseif os(OSX)
    func myFunc(color: NSColor?) {
        self.myFuncX(color)
    }
#endif

private func myFuncX(color: AnyObject?) {
    #if os(iOS)
        myColor = color as! UIColor
    #elseif os(OSX)
        myColor = color as! NSColor
    #endif
}
```

Is there any better way?

Comment: Yes, sorry... I just didn't testet the code on iOS ;) I edited my post.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be able to use `typealias` for the color class, like this:

```
#if os(iOS)
    typealias XColor = UIColor
#elseif os(OSX)
    typealias XColor = NSColor
#endif

func myFunc(color: XColor?) {
    self.myFuncX(color)
}
```

The idea is to limit conditional compile to a type definition for `XColor`, and then using that type alias in place of `UIColor` or `NSColor`, as required on the particular system.